# Nested Class / Objects Binding in CollectionView in MAUI

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui, collectionview

I have a class with nested classes / objects:

```cs
public class MyTasks
{
    public TaskDetails TaskDetails { get; set; }
}
        
public partial class TaskDetails
{    
    public TaskIndividual TaskIndividual { get; set; }
    public Categories Categories { get; set; }
}
        
public partial class TaskIndividual
{
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
        
public partial class Categories
{
    public Category[] Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{
    public string CategType { get; set; }
}
```

I am binding it in MAUI in CollectionView as:

```xml
<CollectionView x:Name="CollectionViewMyTasks" IsGrouped="True">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding MyTasks.TaskDetails.TaskIndividual.TaskName}">
                <Label Text="{Binding MyTasks.TaskDetails.Categories.Category[0]}">
            </VerticalStackLayout>
       </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

It is throwing unhandled error, not even entering the try catch block. I don't have option to modify the class structure because of the test data I am receiving in this format.

Any guidance on how to bind to Collection view will shall be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:

CollectionViewMyTasks.ItemSource = List;

Comment: What is ItemsSource?

Comment: Your Binding expression is illegal. A path of a binding is supposed to be a **property path**. `TaskDetails` should be a property of `MyTasks` and also `MyTasks ` should be a property of the current DataContext. Supplying a Type path can't work because it provides no instances.

Comment: I think you should start with this basic example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data.

Comment: You can only bind to properties of class instances (= objects), but your code doesn't provide any objects, just types. You're also not setting the `ItemsSource` property of the CollectionView, that would be any kind of enumerable that holds the instances that you could bind to.